# Why does DocumentHelper.CopyDocument place the new document in "Published" workflow step?

Tags: kentico

I'm trying to copy a document using the Kentico 11 API and when using Document.CopyDocument the resulting TreeNode is automatically placed into the "Published" workflow step instead of "Edit" as one would expect.  Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

I've tried both methods for DocumentHelper.CopyDocument including the method using CopyDocumentSettings, neither give the option to specify the initial workflow step.

```cs
TreeNode newDoc = DocumentHelper.CopyDocument(document, parentDoc, true, _treeProvider);
// also tried this
TreeNode newDoc = DocumentHelper.CopyDocument(new CopyDocumentSettings(document, parentDoc, _treeProvider));
```

Neither give me the option to specify workflow step, they only push it into "published". I can create a new version of the document, but that doesn't prevent the copy from being published initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it copies the workflow status of the current page but I could be wrong.  What I'd suggest is below.  This code checks to see if the page is using check in/out and then uses workflow to set the newly created page to the first step in the workflow (which should be "edit").

```
TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider();
var treeNode = DocumentHelper.GetDocument(4, tree);
var targetNode = DocumentHelper.GetDocument(5, tree);
CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode newPage = DocumentHelper.CopyDocument(treeNode, targetNode, false);

WorkflowManager workflowManager = WorkflowManager.GetInstance(tree);
WorkflowInfo workflow = workflowManager.GetNodeWorkflow(page);

if (!newPage.IsCheckedOut)
{
    newPage.CheckOut();
}

if (workflow != null)
{
    if (!workflow.WorkflowAutoPublishChanges)
    {
        newPage.MoveToFirstStep("Copying the page from another page.");
    }
}

if (newPage.IsCheckedOut)
{
    newPage.CheckIn();
}
```

Comment: Used a solution similar to this, same resulting behavior. Thanks, Brenden!

Answer (score 0):

I should have waited longer to post this question, turns out you can use the WorkflowManager in the API to push the document to the first step in the workflow:

```cs
newDoc.WorkflowManager.MoveToFirstStep(newDoc);
```

That pushes the document to the "Edit" step without affecting the workflow history, its as if the document was never published.